# What suffix should you use when you are a PhD Scholar filling out membership form for IEEE Xplore?

Tags: phd, ieee, titles

I was filling IEEE Xplore membership form. In the form, there was a field "Suffix", the values for this field are I, II, III, IV, Jr., M.D., P. Eng, PE, PhD, Sr., V.

Which one does best describe me? Currently I am a Research/PhD scholar in a department of information technology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about academia.

Comment: When you say "PhD Scholar", you mean you are currently completing your PhD? i.e., you don't have a PhD?

Answer (score 1):

Names are complicated, and some people are very touchy about getting theirs exactly as they want it. In English-based naming, this can often include prefixes (e.g., "Sir" in "Sir Walter Scott") and [suffixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_(name)) (e.g., "Jr." as in "Martin Luther King, Jr.").

This form is making things more complicated and confusing by combining two orthogonal categories of suffix:

- Generational suffixes:  I, II, III, IV, Jr., Sr., V.
- Academic suffixes:  M.D., P. Eng, PE, PhD

And what should you do? Just leave this field blank.
If your name had a generational suffix, you wouldn't be asking this question.
From your comment, you don't have an academic suffix yet.

Even if you did have an academic suffix, you might not want to add it anyway. In many parts of American scientific or professional society, for example, people do not bother to use their academic titles (it's always a little weird to me to be addressed as "Dr. Beal", and I would never ask somebody to call me "Jacob Beal, Ph.D.").  In many parts of Europe, on the other hand, such titles are used much more commonly and comfortably.

Comment: P.Eng and PE are technically professional suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have one of these titles?

More specifically, as a 'PhD scholar', are you still working towards your​ PhD or have you already defended?

Is your name 'snowbell', 'snowbell the third', or 'snowbell junior'?

If the former, leave the field empty.

Comment: I am working towards my PhD...It has been only 6 months that I have joined the PhD program

Comment: If the other conditions mentioned don't apply, leave the field empty.